# Can't access a newly installed PostgreSQL from a php script

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx, pdo

First of all I am new to PostgreSQL coming from MySQL. I have just installed PostgreSQL from the Fedora repositories and created the postgres user as per the fedora wiki pages, by su-ing into the postgres user and creating its role using the psql shell.

```
# su - postgres
$ psql
> \password
```

Then I created a test script that is served through nginx that will create a test DB and populate it. I'm trying to log in from the script by using the postgres user and its password via peer authentication, with the following pdo dsn:

new PDO('pgsql:user=postgres password=**********');

However, after struggling with SELinux, the connection fails saying that the peer authentication failed, so I looked into the postgresql logs and found that:

> The delivered username (postgres) and the athenticated username (apache) do not match.

So I can deduce that the user that owns the process that's trying to access the db is the user that's being authenticated, so I assume I have to create the corresponding role for the apache user in the db. But why does it do this? Is it some sort of security measure? Is there a way to use the postgres role or am I bound to the apache role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use the `postgres` user for applications**. It's an administrative role. It's like running a web server as `root`. Create less-privileged users for your applications. You may also want to `CREATE DATABASE ... WITH OWNER myappuser;` to give the app ownership of  a database, unless you plan to use finer-grained security.

Create a user for your application to use. Set a randomly generated password, and record that password so your app can use it.

Create a database for the app to use, with the app user as the owner of the database. (This isn't ideal, but it's the simple way. To learn more, read the PostgreSQL manual's chapters on security and privileges.)

Modify `pg_hba.conf` to add an entry for the user on that database that uses `md5` authentication, at least for the database(s) of interest. Make sure the entry is *above* the default `peer` entries.

Then reload PostgreSQL's configuration - `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`.

Your app can now connect to PostgreSQL using a password, but you can still get simple `peer` authentication with `psql` on the command line.

Comment: Ok, I have another few questions: Is there a more secure method than md5? Is it safe to use the apache user/role (since it's what's being authenticated)? Is it safe to create another UNIX user and then create its role in the DBMS?

Comment: @arielnmz For local loopback md5 is fine. For non-loopback I strongly advise using SSL. There's work in progress, hopefully for 9.6, on supporting proper HMAC-based negotiated authentication with multiple algorithms. I recommend creating a new PostgreSQL user for each application and giving it a different password. No need to create a unix user, nor any point doing so; that's only for `peer` authentication.

Comment: Thank you, just one more question: Is peer autentication safer? Which one is, ideally, the best method?

Comment: If there was a simple one-size-fits-all answer to that, then there'd only be one authentication method. I've given my advice on what to use for a webapp running on the local host.